# How to run this code every 5000ms in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

In my application I want check internet and when connected load some data, if not connected check data any **5000ms** and check this 3 level (15000ms), if in this 15000ms not connected show user "Internet Not Connected" and when connected internet get this data.

**My code:**

```
private void retrofitData(boolean isConnect) {
    if (isConnect) {
        try {
            Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
            Call<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getColoniesResponse();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> call, Response<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> response) {
                    try {
                        if (response != null) {
                            if (response.body() != null) {
                                // first remove
                                models.clear();
                                // then fill
                                models.addAll(response.body().getCategories());
                                mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                colonies_RecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);
                                CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();

                                showHelp();
                            } else {
                                CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
                                new SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                                        .setTitleText("title")
                                        .setContentText("message")
                                        .setConfirmText("ok")
                                        .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                                finish();
                                                startActivity(getIntent());
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(context);
                            TastyToast.makeText(context, "error", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                        }
                        checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    new SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("title")
                            .setContentText("message")
                            .setConfirmText("ok")
                            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                    finish();
                                    startActivity(getIntent());
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ServerEx", "Error : " + e);
        }
    } else {
        checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (mAdaper != null) {
            mAdaper.clear();
            colonies_RecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);
        }
        categoryCheckNet_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadData();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Please help me. I am amateur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place this method in your Conastant class where you place utility methods:

```
public abstract static class BackoffCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

        private static int RETRY_COUNT = 3;
        private static final double RETRY_DELAY = 5000;
        private int retryCount = 0;

         protected BackoffCallback(int retryNum) {
            RETRY_COUNT=retryNum;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(final Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
            retryCount++;
            if (retryCount <= RETRY_COUNT) {
                int expDelay = (int) (RETRY_DELAY);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        retry(call);
                    }
                }, expDelay);
            } else {
                onFailedAfterRetry(t);
            }
        }

        private void retry(Call<T> call) {
            call.clone().enqueue(this);
        }

        public abstract void onFailedAfterRetry(Throwable t);

    }
```

And use it in main activity like:

```
 private void retrofitData(boolean isConnect) {
    if (isConnect) {
        try {
            Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
            Call<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getColoniesResponse();


            call.enqueue(new Constants.BackoffCallback<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse>(3) {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> call, Response<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> response) {
                try {
                        if (response != null) {
                            if (response.body() != null) {
                                // first remove
                                models.clear();
                                // then fill
                                models.addAll(response.body().getCategories());
                                mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                colonies_RecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);
                                CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();

                                showHelp();
                            } else {
                                CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
                                new SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                                        .setTitleText("title")
                                        .setContentText("message")
                                        .setConfirmText("ok")
                                        .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                                finish();
                                                startActivity(getIntent());
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(context);
                            TastyToast.makeText(context, "error", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                        }
                        checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailedAfterRetry(Throwable t) {

            new SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                            .setTitleText("title")
                            .setContentText("message")
                            .setConfirmText("ok")
                            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                    finish();
                                    startActivity(getIntent());
                                }
                            })
                            .show();

            }
        });


        } 
    } else {
        checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (mAdaper != null) {
            mAdaper.clear();
            colonies_RecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);
        }
        categoryCheckNet_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadData();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. can you send me full code with my above codes? pleaseeee. I ama amateur. please

Comment: above code try 3 times for 5000 ms, after that onFailedAfterRetry called and show no internet dialog

Comment: Thanks my friend <3